# How to classify two very similar images using Deep Learning?

Tags: computer-vision, image-classification

I have a scenario where I have to classify two images taken from a still CCTV camera which would be very similar except the central region where I have to detect if a technician is working on the machine or not.

Without technician:

[image]

With technician:

[image]

I want the classifier to concentrate on the central region.

I can find architectures where I can classify "cat vs dog" or "rock-papers-scissors" kind of images like this one ([Rock Papers Scissors on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%202%20-%20Part%208%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook%20(RockPaperScissors).ipynb#scrollTo=it1c0jCiNCIM)). Since many areas in the image are going to be same, how can I specify the area the model should concentrate on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to focus on the technician and not on the whole image context, just use an object detector.

[image: human detected on image]

**Object detection models:**

https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 (pytorch)

https://github.com/wizyoung/YOLOv3_TensorFlow

https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI (library)

Comment: hi Zabir..thanks for your help!
The goal is to detect if the machine is attended or not..
The attendant can change so will its clothes daily..
I want to check if the person is facing the machine. If he is standing with his back towards the machine..in that case the machine is not being attended.. I need to check that..

i guess your solution will only help me detecting a human in the image.. whats ur opinion in this

Comment: Your problem description is very specific, however, no matter what, classification is definitely not the way to go. You need to use pose estimation probably to estimate how the person is standing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like labelImg (https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to build a training set of images - you could do a set in which you differentiate "area occupied" and "area unoccupied".    This may be vulnerable to changes in the area, though.

An alternative is to train on a person (meaning, in labelImg you put the boundary box around the person), and you interpret your classifier's output such that, probability of the person has to be above a threshold to indicate presence.

If you need a tutorial on how to do this end-to-end I recommend this one:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

Comment: thanks for your answer.. can u please clarify what u mean by "This may be vulnerable to changes in the area, though."